# Kendo Hierarchy: Get subdetails in kendo grid rows

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a nested (hierarchical) kendo grid and I'm performing a batch edit on it. But my problem is when I will create new record I will not be able to save the sub details only the details of the parent row.

Example:

```
----------------------------------
FirstName             LastName
----------------------------------
Jack                  Mesh
----------------------------------
   Subject            Code
   -------------------------------
   English            101
   Math               111
```

When I click save changes, only Jack Mesh will be save. The subjects which supposed to be the sub details are not saving along.

Is there a way I could manipulate this to be able to get the parent row with its sub rows?

Thank you.

Comment: There is a theoretical work around for the situation, You can call a Commit rows of the Child Grid by calling $("#CHILDgrid").data("kendoGrid").saveChanges(); once the Parent save is completed successfully and which will commit the Child Grid and thus handles saving of the Child Grid Rows for you. I will try get a working demo of above Theory.

Comment: @D_Learning - thanks! I'll try what you suggest. Hopefully this would work.